# Django : How to change redirect destination domain of HttpResponseRedirect

Tags: django, apache, redirect

A different site redirects users to my site. Django host two domains on my server

```
 1. domain1.com
 2. domain2.com -> domain1.com/domain2 ( using ProxyPass ReverseProxyPass in apache)
```

Based on credentials passed in the 'request' passed by referring site, I know where to redirect to the user. But I have a constraint that I need to use a particular view method having  `httpredirectresponse(reverse('DemoVar_response'))` every time. My code looks something like this

app/views.py

```
 return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('DemoVar_response',args=['Successful']))
```

app/urls.py

```
 url(r'^response/(?P<response>[\s\w\d-]+)/$','response', name='DemoVar_response')
```

In case of call from internal link, `HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('DemoVar_response'))` leads to the domain of origin of request, but since I get a redirect request from different website, HttpResponseRedirect falls back to default site.

How can I make HttpPresponseRedirect go to the appropriate domain? I have the destination domain info at the time of redirect, but where should I set it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HttpResponseRedirect` simply takes a URL. And `reverse` simply returns a path, ie a URL without the domain.

So you can easily do:

```
import urlparse
domain = request.GET['domain'] # or however you are getting it
destination = reverse('DemoVar_response',args=['Successful'])
full_address = urlparse.urljoin(domain, destination)
return HttpResponseRedirect(full_address)
```

`urlparse.urljoin` simply joins the two elements of the URL together, ensuring that slashes aren't duplicated and so on.

Comment: Its urlparse.urljoin rather than urlparse.join. Other than that, your solution worked perfectly.